# Problem with relaxed LASSO using glmnet within mlr3: object 'cv' not found

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet, mlr3

I need to replicate some relaxed LASSO regression R code that currently uses the `glmnet` package directly. I want to transfer the code to the `mlr3` framework so that the model can be compared with other machine learning methods.

The tuning of the hyperparameter `lambda` with the learner `classif.cv_glmnet` from `mlr3` works, but the learner `classif.glmnet` gives an error when trained, seemingly because of the `relax` option that needs a `cv` object.

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(glmnet)

# define task
task.sonar <- mlr_tasks$get("sonar")

# tune lambda via cross validation
learner.sonar.lasso.cv <- lrn("classif.cv_glmnet", alpha = 1, relax = TRUE, gamma = 0, nfolds = 15)
set.seed(1112)
learner.sonar.lasso.cv$train(task.sonar)

# fit full model 
learner.sonar.lasso <- lrn("classif.glmnet", alpha = 1, lambda = learner.sonar.lasso.cv$model$lambda, relax = TRUE, gamma = 0)
learner.sonar.lasso$train(task.sonar)
# Error in eval(call, parent.frame()) : object 'cv' not found

# without the relax option, the training is possible
learner.sonar.lasso.2 <- lrn("classif.glmnet", lambda = learner.sonar.lasso.cv$model$lambda, alpha = 1)
learner.sonar.lasso.2$train(task.sonar)
```

I am not sure if this is an issue with the `mlr3` package or with general object visibility. Looking at the code of the `glmnet::glmnet()` function and searching the internet have not helped me so far. Can someone provide a solution or a hint? Thank you.

Edit: I hope this is what is meant by "full error trace":

```
Fehler in eval(call, parent.frame()) : Objekt 'cv' nicht gefunden
23: eval(call, parent.frame())
22: eval(call, parent.frame())
21: update.default(fit, x = x, lambda = lam0, exclude = exclude, 
        ..., relax = FALSE)
20: update(fit, x = x, lambda = lam0, exclude = exclude, ..., relax = FALSE)
19: update(fit, x = x, lambda = lam0, exclude = exclude, ..., relax = FALSE)
18: relax.glmnet(fit, x = x, y = y, weights = weights, offset = offset, 
        lower.limits = lower.limits, upper.limits = upper.limits, 
        penalty.factor = penalty.factor, check.args = FALSE, ...)
17: (if (cv) glmnet::cv.glmnet else glmnet::glmnet)(x = data, y = target, 
        alpha = 1, lambda = c(0.215936661924212, 0.196753444025244, 
        0.179274410333256, 0.163348165820228, 0.148836764975169, 
        0.135614516986089, 0.123566897066315, 0.112589554495583, 
        0.10258740878401, 0.0934738261303851, 0.0851698690416218, 
        0.0776036126139594, 0.070709521553854, 0.0644278825426172, 
        0.0587042870282161, 0.0534891599644241, 0.048737330415487, 
        0.0444076403070864, 0.0404625879347901, 0.0368680031422287, 
        0.0335927513555476, 0.0306084639106231, 0.0278892923372648, 
        0.0254116844721328, 0.0231541804611657, 0.0210972268845912, 
        0.0192230073945579, 0.0175152883984538, 0.0159592784512928, 
        0.0145415001392945, 0.0132496733449733, 0.0120726088826358, 
        0.0110001115830068, 0.0100228919875504, 0.00913248588762428, 
        0.00832118101155355, 0.00758195022462301, 0.00690839066339795, 
        0.00629466827718419, 0.00573546729627189, 0.00522594418928135, 
        0.00476168571081132, 0.00433867067601858, 0.00395323513103854, 
        0.00360204061756966, 0.00328204525674471, 0.00299047740183128, 
        0.00272481163155367, 0.00248274687610199, 0.00226218648636621, 
        0.00206122007376465, 0.00187810696337197, 0.0017112611170257, 
        0.0015592373958224, 0.00142071904301588, 0.00129450627890011, 
        0.00117950590889143, 0.00107472185480002, 0.000979246527277137, 
        0.000892252964710358, 0.000812987670477706, 0.000740764086520378, 
        0.00067495664670528, 0.000614995358470452, 0.00056036086582217, 
        0.00051057995092179, 0.00046522143529921, 0.000423892445191232, 
        0.000386235008656977, 0.000351922954996181, 0.000320659089614627, 
        0.000292172619866747, 0.000266216809579269, 0.000242566841940519, 
        0.000221017872244753, 0.000201383253625311, 0.000183492920408743, 
        0.00016719191508731, 0.00015233904615118, 0.000138805665155114, 
        0.000126474552427178, 0.00011523890176802, 0.000105001395346671, 
        9.56733607800451e-05, 8.71740030951775e-05, 7.94297049218221e-05, 
        7.23733888540074e-05, 6.59439364576355e-05, 6.00856588918438e-05, 
        5.47478145589076e-05, 4.98841696047939e-05, 4.54525974636365e-05, 
        4.1414713977575e-05, 3.77355449315419e-05, 3.43832231233436e-05, 
        3.13287123451996e-05, 2.85455558860014e-05, 2.60096473759378e-05, 
        2.36990219886514e-05, 2.15936661924212e-05), relax = TRUE, 
        family = "binomial")
16: eval(expr, p)
15: eval(expr, p)
14: eval.parent(expr, n = 1L)
13: invoke(if (cv) glmnet::cv.glmnet else glmnet::glmnet, x = data, 
        y = target, .args = pv)
12: glmnet_invoke(data, target, pv)
11: .__LearnerClassifGlmnet__.train(self = self, private = private, 
        super = super, task = task)
10: get_private(learner)$.train(task)
9: .f(learner = <environment>, task = <environment>)
8: eval(expr, p)
7: eval(expr, p)
6: eval.parent(expr, n = 1L)
5: invoke(.f, .args = .args, .opts = .opts, .seed = .seed, .timeout = .timeout)
4: encapsulate(learner$encapsulate["train"], .f = train_wrapper, 
       .args = list(learner = learner, task = task), .pkgs = learner$packages, 
       .seed = NA_integer_, .timeout = learner$timeout["train"])
3: learner_train(learner, task, train_row_ids = train_row_ids, test_row_ids = test_row_ids, 
       mode = mode)
2: .__Learner__train(self = self, private = private, super = super, 
       task = task, row_ids = row_ids)
1: learner.sonar.lasso$train(task.sonar)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post the **full** error trace (as text, not screenshot) - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Hmm, as far as I can tell this is a glmnet bug.